# ML : Dummy variable trap or reason why do we have n-1 dummy variables?

Tags: dummy-variable

Is it possible to explain dummy variable trap or reason why do we have n-1 dummy variables..
If we have n dummy variables, what would be the effect...

n is unique categories..